# how to verify user group on FMP database

Tags: filemaker

I want to know how to verify user permission group on Filemaker Pro database.

I am new to FMP database.

In Sybase database , we use sp_helpuser "usernamexx" ,gives the Group_name(contains user permission group value, ex: read-write, or read,..).

Basically what I am trying to see is I want to check if given user is having read & write access to the fmp database without actually writing anything to that database.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check if given user is having read & write access to the fmp
>   database

You can check which privilege set the current user belongs to by calling the `Get(AccountPrivilegeSetName)` function. You cannot "query" the privilege set itself for specific privileges.

Comment: thanks @michael.hor257k. I am actually trying to run a sql query from java. can I use this command from java odbc. what does it return? Do I need to pass anything in place of AccountPrivilegeSetName?

Comment: I don't think it's possible through SQL. AFAIK, you can only get the current account name, by calling the CURRENT_USER function. If you keep a Users table with {account name; privilege set} pairs, you could look up the corresponding set from there.